# Can ElasticSearch return relevant passages and not the entire document

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, search-engine

I'm looking for a search engine that is able to return just relevant passages as a result and not the entire documents. Is ElasticSearch able to do this?

Comment: I mean text passages

Comment: Are we talking about the fields (like you have 10 fields and a match in one of them, then you'd only return that one) or the relevant part of a very long field (like 2K characters and you only want 20 before and after the match)?

Comment: I have a set of keywords and I want to get just the paragraphs containing these keywords and belonging to my text documents

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to extract part of a long document, look at [Highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html). Specifically parameters like `fragment_size` (100 characters by default) or `boundary_chars` will help you to build that functionality.