# How to apply Boolean(must, should) in highlighted part of elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am trying to apply must/ should in the query but highlighted part didn't give the desired result.
In the elasticsearch reference, I got to know that 
`Highlighters don’t reflect the boolean logic of a query when extracting terms to highlight` but I want to apply boolean logic in my highlight. How to do that?

**This is my index**

```
PUT myindex/_doc/1
{
    "name" : "ram",
    "lastname" : "asb",
    "job_description" : "Systems administrator and Linux specialit",
   "sections":[
       {
         "text":"  provided, that Holdings may incur Indebtedness  or issue shares of Disqualified Stock, and any Restricted Subsidiary may incur Indebtedness  and issue shares of Disqualified Stock and any Restricted Subsidiary that is not the Issuer or a Subsidiary Guarantor may issue shares of Preferred Stock, if (i) the  on a consolidated basis of Holdings and its Restricted Subsidiaries for the most recently ended four fiscal quarters for which internal financial statements are available immediately preceding the date on which such additional Indebtedness is incurred or such Disqualified Stock or Preferred Stock is issued would  (ii) the Consolidated  on a consolidated basis of Holdings and its Restricted Subsidiaries for the most recently ended four fiscal quarters for which internal financial statements are available immediately preceding the date on which such additional Indebtedness is incurred or such  been equal"
       },
       {
         "text":"Indebtedness incurred pursuant to any by Holdings or any Restricted Subsidiary and the  and creation of  and bankers’ acceptances thereunder ; provided that immediately after giving effect to any such incurrence or issuance (including pro forma application of the net proceeds therefrom), the then outstanding aggregate principal amount of all Indebtedness incurred or issued under this clause (1) does not exceed the sum  an additional amount after all amounts have been incurred under clause (1)(a), if after giving pro forma effect to the incurrence of such additional amount (including a pro forma application of the net proceeds therefrom), the Consolidated  would have been equal; provided that for purposes of determining the amount that may be incurred under this clause (1)(b) only, all Indebtedness incurred under this clause (1)(b) shall be deemed to be included in clause (1) of the definition of “Consolidated "
       }
    ] 
}
```

**This is my query**

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "_source": false, 
  "query":{
    "nested":{
      "path": "sections",
      "query":{
        "bool":{
          "must": [
            {
               "match":{"sections.text":"Consolidated"}
            },
            {
               "match":{"sections.text":"forma"}
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
    "highlight": {
       "fragment_size" : 200,
      "no_match_size": 0, 
        "fields" : {
          "sections.text" : {}
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my output

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "myindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.3312968,
        "highlight" : {
          "sections.text" : [
            "on a <em>consolidated</em> basis of Holdings and its Restricted Subsidiaries for the most recently ended four fiscal quarters for which internal financial statements are available immediately preceding the date",
            "by Holdings or any Restricted Subsidiary and the  and creation of  and bankers’ acceptances thereunder ; provided that immediately after giving effect to any such incurrence or issuance (including pro <em>forma</em>",
            "principal amount of all Indebtedness incurred or issued under this clause (1) does not exceed the sum  an additional amount after all amounts have been incurred under clause (1)(a), if after giving pro <em>forma</em>",
            "effect to the incurrence of such additional amount (including a pro <em>forma</em> application of the net proceeds therefrom), the <em>Consolidated</em>  would have been equal; provided that for purposes of determining",
            "the amount that may be incurred under this clause (1)(b) only, all Indebtedness incurred under this clause (1)(b) shall be deemed to be included in clause (1) of the definition of “<em>Consolidated</em>"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

We can clearly see that, it won't give output as (consolidated AND forma)

**If someone queries a AND b**

```
GET index1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "FIELD": "a"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "FIELD": "b"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
    "highlight": {
       "fragment_size" : 200,
      "no_match_size": 0, 
        "fields" : {
          "sections.text" : {}
        }
    }
}
```

**My desire output will be**

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "myindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.371541,
        "highlight" : {
          "sections.text" : [
            "fgfg <em>a</em> fgrgth <em>b</em>"
         ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: .. but both `consoldiated` and `forma` is highlighted in your example? How does that differ from your desired output?

Comment: In highlight, I got 5 output which is separated with comma [ " ", " " ]. So let's name them as output1, output2..., outpu5. output1 starts with "on", output2 starts with "by' and so on. We got only "consolidated" in output1 but as I have written must condition I should get both "consolidated" and "forma" in output1 and also for other outputs. How to do that?

Comment: Highlighting matches of `term_a AND term_b` implies querying `term_a AND term_b` - *Captain Obvious was here*

Comment: I didn't get you @EricLavault. My objective is to extract the paragraph from the text so I am using highlights of elasticsearch and I want whatever query I am writing(must, should, etc), highlighter should also follow and it should give me that result

Comment: My problem is similar to this question [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53904137/can-elasticsearch-return-relevant-passages-and-not-the-entire-document) but there he just wants to get a paragraph which he can get from using highlighter but I want to use boolean logic in highlighter and from that I want result. How to do that?

Comment: The splitting happens because of the length of the field - each highlighted part only includes a part of the complete text of the field. What you're really asking for is to return the complete text as a single blob with the appropriate matches highlighted? Set `number_of_fragments` to `0` to achieve that.

Comment: Even I set **number_of_fragments** to **0**  it won't work. Boolean logic is not working in highlighter.

Comment: What to do if I want a paragraph from my text using boolean logic?

Comment: I'm really not understanding what you're asking about. Your boolean logic _is_ being applied to the search result - it's highlighting both `consolidated` _and_ `forma` - both required to retrieve the document. The reason for five entries being returned is that `number_of_fragments` is `5` by default - these are fragments _from the same field that matched_, just split into fragments because of the size of the field (and the location of the hits inside the document being further than the length of the highlight apart).

Comment: I meant it seems good to me : `consolidated` and `forma` are both highlighted because both matches - *there is no boolean logic issue* - But as Mats said : **the size of the field !** -> think about the extreme case, whatever the field length, suppose both of your searched terms are placed as follows : 1st term is the 1st token and the 2nd term is the last token of the field ; then if you want to highlight both terms in the same snippet, you have to extend the `fragment_size` to nearly the length of the field, or set it to to 0 to never split any sentence.

Comment: @MatsLindh & EricLavault thanks for participating in my post. I got your point but it's not solving my business need. What my requirement is to search for a paragraph in text from a large amount of unstructured text data so I am using queries and to highlight that paragraph I am using highlighter here. Could you please suggest me some other way in Elasticsearch to do that?

Comment: In that case I guess you want to perform the _search_ against a paragraph as well, and not the whole document? If that's the case, index each paragraph as an individual document.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. I will try and let you know.